# How to replace empty values in DataFrame, through lookup of other row

Tags: python, pandas

Please consider the following `DataFrame` code

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

lookup = pd.DataFrame([
    ['IJK', '009', None],
    ['DEF', None, 'CM002'],
    ['GHI', '003', 'CM003'],
    ['GHI', None, 'CM004'],
], columns=['Key', 'Lookup1', 'Lookup2'])
```

My question is about the rows that have key `GHI` in the column.  I would like to find an easy way to replace the empty values (None) by the given value `003` in the same column of another row that has the same Key column

So, I hope to start from this situation:

```
|   | Key | Lookup1 | Lookup2 |
|---|-----|---------|---------|
| 0 | IJK | 009     | None    |
| 1 | DEF | None    | CM002   |
| 2 | GHI | None    | CM003   |
| 3 | GHI | 003     | CM004   |
```

And arrive at this situation

```
|   | Key | Lookup1 | Lookup2 |
|---|-----|---------|---------|
| 0 | IJK | 009     | None    |
| 1 | DEF | None    | CM002   |
| 2 | GHI | 003     | CM003   |
| 3 | GHI | 003     | CM004   |
```

EDITED:

- Updated sample to add case where empty row is positioned before the other row

Comment: Can you assume that there is no more than one row with a value in `Lookup1` and the same `Key`?

Comment: Good catch, Itamar.  And yes, that's the assumption.  It would be ideal if the 'solution' would take the first 'non-empty' value, though

Comment: I can edit my solution to work with your 'ideal... though', but it won't be as elegant as the accepted answer...

Comment: and I've tested the accepted answer, which also works with multiple rows. so I'm good.  tx for you help

Comment: Does it work on the problematic dataframe in my example? I'm thinking the last, not first, non-None value would be used.

Comment: you're right.  and especially when the empty row would come before the other, is the catch I need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215471/discussion-between-sam-vanhoutte-and-itamar-mushkin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
lookup.groupby("Key")[["Key","Lookup1","Lookup2"]].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Output:

```
    Key  Lookup1  Lookup2
0   IJK  009     None
1   DEF  None    CM002
2   GHI  003     CM003
3   GHI  003     CM004
```

**EDIT**

In case of this situation:

```
lookup = pd.DataFrame([
    ['IJK', '009', None],
    ['DEF', None, 'CM002'],
    ['GHI', None, 'CM004'],
    ['GHI', '003', 'CM003'],
    ["ABC",'001',"CM002"],
    ["ABC",None,"CM005"]
], columns=['Key', 'Lookup1', 'Lookup2'])
```

You can fill in both directions:

```
lookup.groupby("Key")[["Key","Lookup1","Lookup2"]].fillna(method='ffill').groupby("Key")[["Key","Lookup1","Lookup2"]].fillna(method='bfill')
```

Output:

```
    Key Lookup1 Lookup2
0   IJK 009     None
1   DEF None    CM002
2   GHI 003     CM004
3   GHI 003     CM003
4   ABC 001     CM002
5   ABC 001     CM005
```

Comment: Great answer - and probably worth noting that this approach works great when the data is already in the proper chronological order - if it is not a sort_values() call before the ffill can help get the data in the right order for this type of approach

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean with chronological order? This solution works even if you switch for example row 0 with row 2, because of the group by, right?

Comment: Hello @DavideBrex, thx for the answer.  Though I liked the elegance the most, a case where row 3 and 4 would be switched in order (so first the empty cell, then the filled cell) would not be caught by your code.  And maybe that's where Chris indicated the sorting ?

Comment: Check out the updated answer, now I included a situation where you can fill the None in both directions.

Comment: @SamVanhoutte , if you want the first not-None value to be used, please make this explicit in your question. After the edit, DavideBrex's solution does fill backward correctly, but still does not work on the "problematic" dataframe I added in my answer.

Comment: @ItamarMushkin My answer assumes that there are not different Lookup1 values for the same key, since the given example in the original question did not mention this possibility.

Comment: you're right and I've updated the sample few minutes ago, indeed.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

A solution where the first non-None value would be used:

```
na_idx = lookup['Lookup1'].isna()
filling_values = lookup.loc[lookup.dropna(
    subset={'Lookup1'})[['Key']].drop_duplicates(keep='first').index].set_index('Key')['Lookup1']
lookup['Lookup1'][na_idx] = lookup['Key'][na_idx].apply(filling_values.get)
```

Input (with multiple values for the 'GHI' key):

```
lookup = pd.DataFrame([
    ['IJK', '009', None],
    ['DEF', None, 'CM002'],
    ['GHI', '003', 'CM003'],
    ['GHI', '00z', 'CM00z'],
    ['GHI', None, 'CM004'],
], columns=['Key', 'Lookup1', 'Lookup2'])
```

Output:

```
    Key Lookup1 Lookup2
0   IJK 009     None
1   DEF None    CM002
2   GHI 003     CM003
3   GHI 00z     CM00z
4   GHI 003     CM004
```

Comment: Thx again.  not sure why my question now has a downvote, but the approved answer does provide the answer to my question as it stands.  Unfortunately, I cannot accept two answers here :(

Answer (score -1):

For dataframe imputing problems I prefer to make a mask with numpy, something like this

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lookup = pd.DataFrame([
    ['IJK', '009', None],
    ['DEF', None, 'CM002'],
    ['GHI', '003', 'CM003'],
    ['GHI', None, 'CM004'],
], columns=['Key', 'Lookup1', 'Lookup2'])

mask = np.where((lookup['Key'] == 'GHI') & (lookup['Lookup1'].isnull()))
lookup.iloc[mask] = '003'

print(lookup)
```

This has a benefit of been much faster than `.apply()`, which is handy for big datasets.

Comment: I was giving GHI as an example.  I reality my dataset is 1000s of records with much more values that will be duplicate keys.  So, I really don't want to hardcode those values.